# How to use Git to sync remote versions

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am working on an algorithm with OpenCV.

1. I git-cloned OpenCV's repo to a local folder.
2. Some new files for the algo is create under the folder/subfolders
3. I created a empty remote repo on a remote server, like github.com

So, what should I do to:

1. upload all files to the remote repo?
2. how to update the files originated from OpenCV?
3. what if I need to modify a OpenCV's file, so that there will be no conflict ?

to my understanding, the 'submodule' is not for the case that 'extra files'/my own files is in the same folder of OpenCV's code base

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you are trying to contribute, then you should fork the repository. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/How_to_contribute

Comment: Hi, Garvita , thanks for the info. The thing is I mainly want to commit the combined code base to my own remote server, while can `pull`/update the latest version of the OpenCV's code base used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you most likely need to do is to fork the original repository, and add this as well as the original github repo as remotes on your local. This way you can sync changes from the original, while pushing your changes to your fork. The whole process is explained very nicely [on github](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/). To summarize:

1. Fork the original repository (from the OpenCV Github Page)

   - This will automatically create a forked project under your username
2. Create a clone of this forked repo on your local machine
3. Add the original repo as a second remote to your local repo.

   ```
   git remote add upstream https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
   ```
4. Now you should have two remote repos, and you can maintain sync between them however you wish.

   ```
   git remote -v
   origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (fetch)
   origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (push)
   upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
   upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (push)
   ```